# Calculating the confidence interval or standard error of a PPV adjusted for prevalence

Tags: standard-error, precision-recall, case-control-study, prevalence

I am trying to evaluate how well a disease test performs in a case-control study. In this example, the prevalence is 0.5%, and the results are below:

|  | Disease + | Disease - |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Test +** | 40 (TP) | 10 (FP) |
| **Test -** | 600 (FN) | 5000 (TN) |

As the sample is enriched for those with the disease, the standard PPV calculation $PPV = \frac{TP}{TP+FP}$ isn't accurate. I can calculate the PPV adjusted for prevalence using $ppv = \frac{p\cdot Sens}{p\cdot Sens + (1-p)\cdot(1-Spec)}$, as in [this page](https://www.omnicalculator.com/statistics/sensitivity-and-specificity), which here gives a PPV of 13.6%.

But given the low prevalence, I am concerned that a small change in the number of false positives could make a large difference to the PPV, so I want to calculate the 95% confidence interval on this PPV.

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9449/how-do-you-compute-confidence-intervals-for-positive-predictive-value) gives the standard error as $SE = \sqrt{ \frac{PPV(1-PPV)}{TP+FP}}$.
This would give a standard error of 4.8%, and if I then use $CI_{PPV} = PPV \pm 1.96*SE$, I get a CI of 4.1%-23.1%.

But:

1. Does this equation still apply when the PPV has been adjusted for prevalence?
2. I have read that as the uncertainty of a proportion is not symmetrical, using the above equation to calculate the CI is not very useful (e.g. in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/805/how-do-i-calculate-the-se-for-ppv-npv-and-dor)).

So, is there a better way to calculate the confidence interval on the PPV in this case?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this further I found that there are multiple possible ways of calculating PPV confidence intervals, but decided to use the standard logit confidence intervals explained in and recommended by this paper: [Confidence intervals for predictive values with an emphasis to case–control studies](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.2677)